# Visual studio IntelliSense not working correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, intellisense

I am just learning how to code in Unity using C#, but I have encountered a problem every time I try and use IntelliSense it shows me this instead of real functions.
[Code suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQRQC.png)
What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Intellisense normally only shows you what the class knows about due to the using statements at the top of the class.  If you add more using namespaces, it will show more shortcuts here.  If you don't do that, you can still spell out the full namespace and it should help narrow down what is available at each level.